# Rails form helper: Override id of Rails hidden model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

According to the [docs for Form Helper's `form_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for):

> The form_for method automatically includes the model id as a hidden
>   field in the form. This is used to maintain the correlation between
>   the form data and its associated model. Some ORM systems do not use
>   IDs on nested models so in this case you want to be able to disable
>   the hidden id.

This makes sense and is important, but if you have two `form_for` calls on the same page, it generates two hidden fields with the same markup and the same id. In my case, it generates this twice on the same page:

```
<input id="clinic_patient_signup_clinic_patient_link_person_attributes_patient_information_attributes_id" name="clinic_patient_signup[clinic_patient_link][person_attributes][patient_information_attributes][id]" type="hidden" value="32" /></div>
```

Is there a way to overwrite the `id` attribute of that input? If I remember correctly, it's just the `name` attribute that is important, and the value can stay the same. Our site has to be [WCAG 2.0 accessibility compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/), and it won't allow two tags on the same page with the same id. (That's also not valid HTML.)

Comment: this question had been ansowered in [here]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682076/change-html-form-id-generated-by-form-for-rails-3-1

Comment: No, that's to change the id of the form. This is the id of the hidden field that `fields_for` adds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `form_for` `:namespace` option.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415985/2511083 for a complete answer.